# Release management not triggered when setting configuration to Release

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, transformation, release-management, ms-release-management

I divide this to two issues , but solving any one of them will solve the other.

Issue 1:
When I use the section at the bottom of the following picture and add "configurations to release", the build is not triggering release management.

I queried the build logs for hours, and saw that it stops the release when it founds out that the configuration "does not match current"

If ConfigurationsToRelease Matches Current
Initial Property Values
Condition = **False**
Final Property Values
Condition = **False**
Final Property Values
Condition = True

before more words, I will show a picture that sums it up:
[the build definition and ms build logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1q3N.png)

in a default case, where configuration to release is blank , release management would continue from this point and write in the logs "Release the build" (as a command that happened) and the build would trigger release management.

If you look at my tfs build configurations, you can see it's exactly the same as the upper regular ms build configurations , but still I get this error of a mismatch. 
In any case I only have only one dialog to fill my configurations at in build definition as shown in the 'configuration dialog' in the above pic.

I succeeded to release once or twice this way in this same project the other day by adding release configurations, it somehow worked, but then stopped working (worked once or twice as a glitch I think like something is cached there) but 99% of the other attempts failed, it was always stopping my trigger from tfs to release since the first time I tried it a few months ago.
**Has someone here experienced it**? I looked in a lot of places and spotted only one guy that complained about it. His solution was to remove it (not exactly a solution)
Is there a build argument that can fix this? (/p:something=something)

Issue 2: if anyone can solve it in a way different than rm configurations , then I don't need issue 1 to be solved.

For any one who is interested why I even messed with release configuration section of build definition, it's because I want rm to **wait** for all transformations to happen before rm intervention, and this seems like a way to tell rm , ok dude , see there? you got 2 configurations to wait for their build.

The thing is that by default when that configuration section is blank, rm is getting in the way of tfs build and tfs build is getting in the way of rm, something like a circular wait. rm expects both transformed folders to exist in build outputs when tfs build is waiting for rm to finish it's run after the first build, tfs wants to continue building the second configuration (and transform) but rm is involved already , seeking for it's second configuration, breaking the build when fails to find it, hence the second configuration will never be created, while rm is still waiting for it and tfs build waits for rm and build breaks. confusing? read again and see the pic below cause it's interesting enough.

more info for clarity: 
the next stage of RM is trying to get something from build outputs folder before it's already there. 
for example , if i set Release build to true , it will only build the first configuration (a folder is created, picture below) , rm will succeed in first step (QA.Release), and continue strait to try and grab Release for its next stage, but it's not built yet by TFS Build , which waits for rm to finish it's weird intervention in the middle of tfs's build work  . and like i said above, I'm sure I've seen it work once or twice in one of my attempted builds.

[the tfs output folder whith release build flag on(only one transform happens) \ when off (all two transforms work) + rm error when on (circular wait)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lisZC.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your situation correctly I think your problem is that you are building multiple configurations. This breaks one of the core tenets of continuous delivery which is that for a given release you should build only **once** and deploy that same build to each stage in your pipeline, in sequence.

In order to do this your build needs to be stage agnostic, which in practice means all your configuration (eg database connection string) needs to be tokensised so that the correct value can be swapped in for the particular stage (QA, Release etc). I have a blog post series [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/) that explains the full process (for a sample web application) in great detail.

Comment: Graham , Life is more complicated than connection string swaps.

Comment: More suggestions ? the described issues are not solved yet .

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve issue 2 , and by doing so, issue 1 is no longer relevant .
i switched to ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml as a build template (found on your C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\Client\bin)

and then the build finished all configurations before RM intervention .

truly seems like a bug in ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml , or this might be because i was using some additional msbuild arguments (which were needed) , or the fact i'm using slow cheetah to create transforms on a windows service (transformations are only introduced in web applications).

either way , i'm now able to perform advanced tasks , like using the transforms to add \ remove tags that should be different in production , for example , i can leave the use of diagnostics in the configuration file for qa use , and remove it for production to make the verbosity lower there . still am using RM **PlaceHolders** technique in conjunction to transformation technology , to enjoy both worlds where it comes to changes related to environments , but still keeping the principles by passing the same build (dlls) through all environments .